# Custom output from a mysql query

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

Consider the following schema:

```
    CREATE TABLE `Result` (
  `startDate` date NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `Result`
(`startDate`,
`description`,
`value`)
VALUES
('2020-09-01' ,'Allowance' ,4000),
('2020-09-01' ,'Salary' ,1500),
('2020-10-01' ,'Allowance' ,2000),
('2020-10-01' ,'Salary' ,3000),
('2020-10-01' ,'Deduction' ,-200);
```

Given a date,the result should show as the total for a description & startdate and the difference between the date selected and previous date(month). So if October was the month selected the result of the query should show as,

```
description SeptemberTotal OctoberTotal Variance
Allowance       4000         2000        -2000
Salary          1500         3000         1500 
Deduction       0            -200         -200
```

My attempt using a union & a pivot,

```
SELECT @selectDate:='2020-10-01'; -- set desired date

SELECT 
    t.month,  
    t.description,
     Gross,
from (
    SELECT 
        DATE_FORMAT(pi.startDate, '%b/%y') AS 'Month',
        SUM(pi.value) AS gross,
        description
    FROM
        Result pi
    WHERE
        pi.startDate = DATE_SUB(@selectDate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) -- select previous month
    GROUP BY description 
    UNION SELECT 
        DATE_FORMAT(pi.startDate, '%b/%y') AS 'Month',
        SUM(pi.value) AS gross,
        description
    FROM
        Result pi
    WHERE
        pi.startDate = @selectDate
    GROUP BY description) t
GROUP BY t.Month,t.description
;
```

which gives the result as,

```
Month   description   Gross
Sep/20  Allowance     4000
Sep/20  Salary        1500
Oct/20  Allowance     2000
Oct/20  Salary        3000
Oct/20  Deduction    -200
```

which is not exactly what the requirement is. I have tried a pivot query as well, that too is not showing the output as required.

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=vVOnslsaBJ)

Comment: Add MonthYear retrieving subquery as a base (or generate it in CTE), LEFT JOIN another src table copy to it. Use client's reporting subsystem for pivotting.

Comment: @Strawberry that will be october total - september total in this case, I have edited the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SET @m1 := '2020-09-01';
SET @m2 := '2020-10-01';

SELECT Result.Description, 
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN Result.startDate = @m1 THEN value END), 0) Total1,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN Result.startDate = @m2 THEN value END), 0) Total2,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN Result.startDate = @m2 THEN value END), 0) -
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN Result.startDate = @m1 THEN value END), 0) Variance
FROM ( SELECT @m1 startDate UNION ALL SELECT @m2 ) baseDates
LEFT JOIN Result USING (startDate)
GROUP BY Result.Description
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1ab0b9066570cc7f50c6b83f87a8e55a)

Answer (score 0):

select
description,

sum(if(startDate between  '2020-11-01 00:00:00' and '2020-11-31 23:59:59' ,value,0)) 1st,

sum(if(startDate between  '2020-12-01 00:00:00' and '2020-12-31 23:59:59',value,0)) 2nd,

sum(if(startDate between  '2020-11-01 00:00:00' and '2020-11-31 23:59:59' ,value,0))-sum(if(created_at between  '2020-12-01 00:00:00' and '2020-12-31 23:59:59',value,0)) Variance

from
Result
where  startDate between  '2020-11-01 00:00:00' and '2020-12-31 23:59:59' group by description